# How to change a gray scale image to red colored image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an image of a thick wave which changes from black to white smoothly like the black slowly changes from dark to white. How can I change this image to red instead of having different shades of black I need different shades of red going from dark red to white.

Comment: Could you show your attempt and the sample image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array of size (rows,cols,3) where (rows,cols) is the size of gray image. Make its red channel equal to 255 and other channels equal to gray image

```
img = imread('moon.tif');

[r,c,z] = size(img);
red_img = uint8(zeros(r,c,3));
red_img(:,:,1) = 255;
red_img(:,:,2) = img;
red_img(:,:,3) = img;

subplot(1,2,1);
imshow(img,[]);
subplot(1,2,2);
imshow(red_img,[]);
```

[image: convert_gray_to_red]